# How write Array formula from R into excel, for example {=C2:C11*D2:D11}

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I use

```
library("openxlsx")
writeFormula (wb , sheet = "data" , 
           x = c ("SUM(A2:A4)", "AVERAGE(B2:B4)", "MEDIAN(C2:C4)") ,sep='')) , 
           startCol =  "X" , startRow = 4 )
```

And into Excel, I see:

```
 1. =SUM(A2:A4)
 2. =AVERAGE(B2:B4)
 3. =MEDIAN(C2:C4)
```

but I want to write the formula with {} and get it in Excel:

```
 1. {=SUM(A2:A4)}
 2. {=AVERAGE(B2:B4)}
 3. {=MEDIAN(C2:C4)}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have to manually edit the array formulas (press '**F2**' key) and then by pressing the **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** for each formula.